# Android 3.0 Action bar Search View

Tags: android, search, android-3.0-honeycomb

In 3.0 tablet gmail app, when I click on the search button(on the action bar), it moves to the right and takes the whole action bar. How can I do this? Only way I can think is that by hiding all the other custom action bar fields when the search button is clicked. Is there an easier way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add an **Action View**. You can control which elements of your action bar are automatically "hidden" when there is no place for them declaring `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` in your menu layout and force the ones that you always want to display using `android:showAsAction="always"`.

Check the [action bar documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) for some samples.